# Monitoring access to nginx server and fighting bots?

Tags: nginx, web-server, ruby-on-rails

I have a potential problem with bad bots, wanted some help dealing with the problem in the most correct way.

I have a Rails app installed on an Nginx server with unicorn, I also have newrelic pro installed.

Today I noticed a bot filling up a form I have on the website every 6 minutes.
My analytics systems completely ignored the bot (woopra and google analytics)

I thought about trying to get that bot's ip address 
But what's the best way to do that? if I got over the server logs there are just too many of them..

Is there a nice monitoring tool to see the live traffic? I couldn't find such a feature on newrelic.. at least not one that will give me the IP addresses.

I also found this github repo:
https://github.com/mariusv/nginx-badbot-blocker
Should I use this list? is it a best practice?

I also found this product:
https://www.shieldsquare.com/integration-options/

that seemed like it can give me a way to block bots. But will I also have a way to track that? if there's a bot alert going on I want to know about it..

Would love some guidance

Thanks

Comment: How did you managed to notice the BOT?

Comment: when that particular form is filled I get an email. I go the same email with same values 800 times. never happened before